# php simple_html_dom select correct table data

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I have table in html file (fragment what interesting me):

```
<h3 class="subTitle">Odbitki</h3>
<div class="subtitleBottomEdge"></div>
<div class="pad10">
  <table class="mainContentArea">
    <tr>
      <td class="labelFont">Wszystkie odbitki:</td>
      <td class="itemFont">49946</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="labelFont">Kompletne odbitki równoważności (A4/Letter):</td>
      <td class="itemFont">49945.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="labelFont">Arkusze dwustronne:</td>
      <td class="itemFont">2735</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

What I need is just to show a number after "Wszystkie odbitki" like: `Wszystkie odbitki: 49946`

I know it is possible in simple_html_dom but I don't know how to do it using PHP.

Code:

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://127.0.0.1/tabela.html');

$table = null;
$needle = 'Odbitki';
foreach($html->find('h3') as $marker) {
  if ($marker->innertext == $needle) {
    $table = $marker->next_sibling();
    break;
  }
}
$data = array();
if ($table) {
  foreach($table->children() as $k => $tr) {
    foreach($tr->children as $td) {
      $data[$k][] = $td->innertext;
    }
  }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Comment: And what is the output now?

Comment: And I suppose `next_sibling()` of `$marker` is `<div class="subtitleBottomEdge">` and not the table.

Comment: This is too complicated for `simple html dom`. A jquery-style parser can do `h3:contains("Odbitki") ~ div td:contains("Wszystkie odbitki") + td`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to provided html structure you need to change this line:

```
if($marker->innertext == $needle) {
    $table = $marker
        // `next_sibling` gets `div class="subtitleBottomEdge"`
        ->next_sibling()
        // `next_sibling` gets `<div class="pad10">`
        ->next_sibling()
        // `first_child` gives you a required table
        ->first_child();
    break;
}
```

**Update** for one cell, for example:

```
foreach($table->children() as $k => $tr) {
    $data[$k][] = $tr
        // `first_child`  gets first `td`
        ->first_child()
        // `next_sibling`  gets second `td`
        ->next_sibling()
        ->innertext;
}
```

Comment: Great! Thx. Now i have correct table.
How can I post now this only 1 cell table? (49946)

Comment: Now i have all the rows from this table but i need to print only this:     [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 49946
        ) and only the number without this all array etc..

Comment: Add `break` where you need.

Answer (score 1):

### **Step 1. Preparation**

> The first thing you'll need to do is download a copy of the
>   simpleHTMLdom library, freely available from sourceforge.

There are several files in the download, but the only one you need is the simple_html_dom.php file; the rest are examples and documentation.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

### Step 2. Parsing Basics

This library is very easy to use, but there are some basics you should review before putting it into action.

**Loading HTML**

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();

// Load from a string
$html->load('<html><body><p>Hello World!</p><p>We're here</p></body>
</html>');

// Load a file
$html->load_file('http://net.tutsplus.com/');
```

You can create your initial object either by loading HTML from a string, or from a file. Loading a file can be done either via URL, or via your local file system.
Once you have your DOM object, you can start to work with it by using find() and creating collections. A collection is a group of objects found via a selector - the syntax is quite similar to jQuery.
**in your own Problem page1.html**

```
   <h3 class="subTitle">Odbitki</h3><div class="subtitleBottomEdge"></div>
        <div class="pad10"><table class="mainContentArea">
          <tr>
            <td class="labelFont">Wszystkie odbitki:</td>
            <td class="itemFont">49946</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="labelFont">Kompletne odbitki równoważności (A4/Letter):</td>
            <td class="itemFont">49945.4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td class="labelFont">Arkusze dwustronne:</td>
          <td class="itemFont">2735</td>
          </tr>
```

In this example HTML, we're going to take a look at how to access the information in the second paragraph, change it, and then output the results.

```
# create and load the HTML
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load("page1.html");

# get an element representing the second paragraph
$element1 = $html->find('.labelFont');
$element2 = $html->find('.itemFont');

# modify it
$element1->innertext .= $element2->innertext;

# output it!
echo $html->save();
```

Comment: Copypasting some info from offsite tutorials is not a good idea.